# Select distinct records applying specific tie rules for duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table `uzer` :

```
id | domain_id
---+-----------
10 | 1  
11 | 1
12 | 2 
13 | 2
```

Table `app` :

```
id| user_id | app_guid  | version | created_at
--+---------+-----------+---------+-------------
1 | 10      | 7...8     | 100     | 2018-01-18    
2 | 11      | 7...8     | 100     | 2018-01-19
3 | 12      | f...4     | 200     | 2018-01-20
4 | 13      | f...4     | 201     | 2018-01-21
5 | 12      | 4...f     | 300     | 2018-01-22
```

`unique(user_id, app_guid)`

An application is identified by it's guid.
Need to select all unique apps in a given domain.

Filtering duplicates :

1. Pick record having the maximum `version` for apps with same `app_guid`
2. Pick record having minimum `id` for apps with same `app_guid` and `version`

For domain 1, record 1 should be picked (for same guid and version pick record with minimum id).
For domain 2, record 4 and 5 should be picked (for same guid pick latest version).

Sql fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3b9d2/1

P.S. Please feel free to change question title to better reflect question content.

Comment: Your data model is quite arcane.  Why do you have duplicate rows for an application in `apps`?  Why do you have `domain_id` in both tables?  Your description doesn't help either.  You talk about choosing a record, but don't specify the table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Because same app can be reported by different users. I dropped the second table to make it simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules:

1. One row per app: `DISTINCT ON (app_guid)`.
2. Prefer highest version, when same then lowest id: `ORDER BY version DESC, id`

The query:

```
select distinct on (app_guid) *
from app
where exists(select 1 from uzer where uzer.id=app.user_id and uzer.domain_id = 1)
order by app_guid, version desc, id;
```

Comment: My mistake, sorry, yes the `app_guid` must be first in `ORDER BY`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you ! I changed a little bit the schema (the `domain_id` is to be resolved via the `uzer` table). Edited your answer, could you check  please whether the edit is correct.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  (SELECT app.id,app.user_id,uzer.domain_id,app.app_guid,app.version,app.created_at,
   row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY domain_id,app_guid ORDER BY version DESC, app.id) as rank
  FROM app,uzer WHERE app.user_id=uzer.id)ranked_app
WHERE rank=1 and ranked_app.domain_id = 1
```

Comment: Make this `ORDER BY version DESC, id)`.

Comment: Would be nice to see how this would change when the `domain_id` is to be resolved from the `uzer` table.

Comment: @Bax, you changed your question. I updated my answer, but you shouldn't change your question like that, it could lead to wrong answers.

Comment: `FROM app,uzer`? This join syntax was made redundant in 1992; why are you still using it?

Comment: It is a completely right syntax, is not redundant at all. It is classic SQL syntax and completely valid for PostgreSQL even in its version 10 as seen [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html)